# How can i display folder in html using express.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, mean-stack

I have a folder in my project (uploads) and i want to show this folder in html file using express.js

and folder have subfolder, with name of usernames like:

uploads > username > and other files, like jpg, txt, and other types

i make

```
fs.readdir('uploads' + req.user.username, (err,data) => {
console.log(data)
}
```

and read the data
but i want to put in html file the sub folder, for user can see the folder

Comment: There is middleware that does just this: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `serve-index` as Jordan had mentioned you can take the returned array of file names and just put them into an object that you render in a Jade/Pug file.

```
router.get('/dir', function (req, res, next) {
  fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, '../views'), function (err, files) {
    // directory.pug 
    res.render('directory', {files: files});
  });
});
```

directory.pug

```
extends layout
block content
  ul
    each file in files
      li= file
```